# Qual é o significado de "dar paleta"?

Tags: significado, expressões-idiomáticas

Na canção [“Realidade Urbana” do rapper português Sam the Kid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDJhYrOtjIo) (com [letra aqui)](https://www.letras.mus.br/sam-the-kid/728820/), ele diz no segundo verso da primeira estrofe:

> Sonho juvenil que ambiciona dar paleta

Qual é o significado de **“dar paleta”** em geral e, claramente, no contexto deste verso?

Comment: Mais abaixo também vem "fdps não compreendi o porquê / A darem paleta já com programas na TV". Não faço a mínima. O ANeves é deve saber.

Comment: acho que paleta é um exemplo de um trecho do repertório

Comment: Nã sei nã senhores...

Comment: A única ideia que tenho, @Jacinto, é que possa ser paleio, letra, *[patoá](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/pato%C3%A1)*. Mas não encaixa muito bem. Para encaixar, devia ser algo como "deitar ares", "armar-se em grande".

Comment: @ANeves, também encontrei a expressão mais ou menos com esse sentido noutras canções rap, tipo 'fazer grande figura, querer causar admiração'. Tava à espera que soubesses: tu costumas saber essas coisas dos submundos do rap, droga, e essas coisas...

Comment: Me parece que "dar paleta" seja sinônimo de "dar uma palinha". Daí, *"dar paleta na TV"*, seria algo como *"dar uma amostra [do trabalho/performance] na TV"*. Outra interpretação que se encaixa no contexto é "marcar presença [na TV]". Não tenho nenhuma base para achar isso, é apenas minha interpretação (possivelmente equivocada), mas eis alguns sites relevantes: [1](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/palinha/), [2](http://linguagista.blogs.sapo.pt/110594.html), [3](http://www.usinadetextos.com.br/lingua-portuguesa/dar-uma-palhinha-ou-palinha/).

Answer (score 1):

*paleta* vem da língua italiana: *paletta*.

Este nome feminino refere-se a: "(pintura) pequena tábua com um oríficio para se meter o polegar, onde o pintor dispõe e combina as tintas". Cá está ela:

[image: exemplo de paleta]

O nome desta peça distintiva da arte da pintura é também utilizado em linguagem figurada. Uma das suas definições é

- arte ou génio do pintor

Isto é, quando se observa, por exemplo, um quadro de Picasso, pode dizer-se que o quadro é uma forma de realização da paleta do Picasso.

A expressão utilzada pelo StK---"***dar** paleta*"---parece relacionar-se com esta figura de estilo. O verbo "dar", no contexto do Hip Hop, soa a *realizar*.

O "Rapper", no sentido particular da letra do StK, ou o artista, num sentido mais geral, vai para além da mera prática da arte; ele concretiza a sua expressão de tal forma que o seu génio se torna percetível através das suas realizações artísticas.

Answer (score 1):

"Dar paleta" ou "mandar paleta" significa, como foi dito nos comentários, "[fazer grande figura](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4516/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-de-dar-paleta#comment12067_4516)", ostentar ou, de forma mais típica, "ter pinta".

Outra expressão sinónima é "mandar cenário".

Comment: Lamento, mas não consigo justificar esta resposta com fontes. Cresci e vivo em Chelas, faz parte do vocabulário daqui há pelo menos 20 anos.

Comment: "Cresci e vivo em Chelas, faz parte do vocabulário daqui há pelo menos 20 anos" é uma informação importante, e uma justificação válida. Eu inclui-la-ia na resposta, em vez de em anexo no comentário. Outra coisa, possivelmente enganaste-te no link na tua resposta; vai dar à outra respostas...

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado. O link vai dar ao teu comentário :)

Comment: Não vi que era essa a intenção. Devo ter saltado a parte em que dizes "dito nos comentários", e quando cliquei o que eu vi foi a outra resposta; o meu comentário estava imediatamente acima, mas a resposta destaca-se.